# Android app to transfer data

Tags: java, android, websocket, httpurlconnection

I am sending data to a server via `HTTPUrlConnection`. It is received on the server side with PHP code and inserted into a MySQL database. Everything is functioning as intended. The issue is that it using a lot of data to do it. The info I am sending is in the variable `unitData` which is between 80 and 200 characters long. The data reportedly being used is 3K to 8K of data each transfer. This seem like a lot of overhead to move 200 bytes. I need this to be as small as possible for my application to work, preferably under 500 bytes. Is there a way to tweak `HTTPUrlConnection` or should I be using Websockets or something else entirely?

```
class dataSender extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String unitData = params[0];
        try {
            URL url = new URL("https://www.website.php");
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            connection.setReadTimeout(10000);
            connection.setConnectTimeout(10000);
            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

            //connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", "" + test.length());
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Language", "en-US");

            connection.setUseCaches (false);
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.setDoOutput(true);

            DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream (connection.getOutputStream ());

            wr.writeBytes ("mydata="+unitData);
            wr.flush ();
            wr.close ();

            //Get Response
            int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
            StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
            if(responseCode == 200) {
                InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
                String line;

                while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                    response.append(line);
                    response.append('\r');
                }
                rd.close();
            }
            else{
                response.append("Error:");
                response.append(responseCode);
            }

            connection.disconnect();

            return response.toString();
            //return "nada";

        } catch (Exception e) {
            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "exception:"+e, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);

            return e.toString();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: You should get rid of the disconnect, as it is preventing connection pooling. You could use a WebSocket if you can keep it open, so the HTTP overhead only happens once. If there was an error you should read the error stream of the connection.

Comment: No errors received. Just unexpectedly high data usage.  I dont think keeping a connection open is wise in this situation as i will only connect about every 4 or 5 hours then just do nothing then wait and connect again. Thank you for the thought.

Comment: Removing the disconnect doesn't keep the connection open for five hours. It just disables connection pooling completely. When operational, it works over much shorter periods than that. I understand about the data usage: it's the topic of your question, and that's why I agreed with your suggestion to use Web sockets. The fact that no errors were received isn't a reason why you shouldn't code correctly the case when they are.

Comment: Ok thanks ill try implementing websockets and report back